# утечка памяти в игровых движках

Tags: flash, разработка-игр, actionscript-3

Хочу сделать какую нибудь игрушку на *as3*. С нуля разбираться особого желания нет, поэтому смотрел в сторону готовых решений.
Собственно пока успел только 2 движка посмотреть, а именно: *Flashpunk*, *Starling*.

В обоих движках наблюдаю следующую картину:

беру "hello world" движка, включаю дебаг панельку, которая показывает *fps/mem* и т.д - Компилю дебаг версию (открывается *flash player*) - проблем нет, делаю билд и смотрю на это дело уже через `index.html` - судя по панельке, память медленно уходит в никуда. Чем активней водишь мышкой по флешке, тем сильнее улетает память (как в панельке, так и в диспетчере задач). Выпиливаю всё, что можно выпилить из "hello world'а", оставляя только панельку, ситуация не меняется.

Мне показалось странным, что на двух просмотренных мной движках проблема даёт о себе знать и пугает пользоваться ими, т.к не хотелось бы, что бы игрок в дальнейшем увидел краш браузера из за нехватки памяти или жестокие тормоза.

Кто нибудь использует эти движки? Наблюдали ли такую проблему?

Возможно это глюк или плохо настроен *flash-develop*? Либо я что-то не знаю о *flash*? (К слову, опыта с *flash* у меня мало, может, это сборщик мусора не хотеть приходить?)

Что думаете на эту тему? Есть ли рекомендации, какой движок использовать, при этом он не страдает такой проблемой.

Буду рад узнать причину такого поведения или моего незнания. Т.к. движки вроде бы популярны, и даже не верится, что такое происходит на пустом месте.

Comment: Странные какие то штуки. Выкладывайте код.

Comment: Кстати Starling не движок, а Flashpunk сильно старенький и простой. Игровой движок это Citrus например.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую его тоже посмотреть

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правильно предположили, что просто не дождались работы GC. Мышка генерит эвенты - они тоже объекты, так что всё логично (наверное). О каких масштабах идёт речь? Современные GC не будут шевелится пока не накопится пара *мега*байт объектов.

Имеет смысл добавить в цикл (или что там у них):

```
System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent(0);
System.gc();
```

и посмотреть ещё раз.

Comment: > Только для отладочной версии Flash Player и приложений AIR. В приложении AIR метод System.gc() работает только в содержимом, выполняющемся в AIR Debug Launcher (ADL), или, в случае с установленным приложением, в содержимом в изолированной программной среде безопасности приложения.

Comment: объем примерно 100кб в 3 секунды. Странно что до поста здесь не заметил работу gc. Сейчас включал - 37.0мб. Вожу быстро мышкой, доходит до 40мб потом скидывает до 37.0. Но если как маньяк водить, доходит скажем до 40.4 и скидывает уже до 37.1 и по нарастающей, после до 37.2, 37.3. Это на Starling, flashpunk позже посмотрю. Наверно всё в порядке

Comment: @noadev лучше конечно воспользоватся встроенными средствами среды для точного контроля используемой памяти. Starling уже довольно взрослый и серьёзный фреймворк, если утечки там и есть, то вряд ли для столь тривиальных случаев (либо вызваны вами, а не фреймворком).